# how to retrieve data from three columns into a one column in the new table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

```
SELECT  Dc.Name AS Market   
        ,R.Name AS Route    
        ,C.Id   
        ,C.ERPCusCode   
        ,C.Name 
        ,C.Address1 AS Address  
        ,C.CustomerGradeId AS volumeClass   
        ,I.ERPItemCode  
        ,H.InvoiceDate  
        ,D.Qty 
FROM InvoiceHeader H
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetail D ON H.InvoiceNo=D.InvoiceNo
INNER JOIN ItemMaster I ON I.Id=D.ItemMasterId
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.Id=H.CustomerId
INNER JOIN DistributionCenter Dc ON Dc.Id=H.DistributionCenterId
INNER JOIN Route R ON R.Id=H.RouteId
WHERE H.Deleted=0 AND H.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/06/06'
AND C.Active=1
```

This is my SQL code and customer table has address 1 , address 2 ,address 3 , address 4 in it i want to get those all fields data into a one column as address in the above code output table.How should i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just concatenate them together?

```
(address1 + ' ' + address 2 + ' ' + address 3 + ' ' + address 4) as address
```

Comment: Yeah this works for me can i ask another q? I want to get the total qty one person has got for a one date (group by date i guess) how should i get it?

Comment: @Tharani . . . You can ask another question *as a question*.  Comments are not for questions.